# VSE Sequencer - imported strips go to random channels when DragnDropped

Tags: interface, import, video-sequence-editor, random

Sorry if this is a bit OCD but does anyone know how to select which channel an imported clip/sequence will appear on in the VSE Sequencer when dragged onto it from the file browser window? I know you get the choice when using the add strip dialogue, but even that seems to reset itself randomly rather than remembering the previous channel selected.

Any thouhgt swould be most welcome, I'm trying to streamline my workflow as much as possible and this is getting to be more than a hiccup.

Many thanks
Adamskibruce

Blender 3.1 on Win 10 Pro 64

Comment: Additionally, even when using the spinner in the 'add strip' dialogue to choose a target channel it actually imports the clip/sequence onto a different channel to that chosen. Can't work out the logic or maybe it's a bug?

Comment: In some of the beta 3.2, 3.3, 3.4 version, drag and drop to mouse cursor position has been implemented. I can't remember which.